# Can't connect to database on InfinityFree

Tags: reactjs, laravel

Now, I'm deploying my website  on InfinityFree. But I can't connect to database.

My website call API from localhost:8000

[illustrations1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1WlR.png)

[illustrations2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K95M.png)

I hope that someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not clear. But when you deploy a project then you don't use localhost. And if the backend is on different origin than make sure to use cors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Looks like my website has redirected to localhost